# xamrin UWP storagefolder.getfilesasync() - operation not supported

Tags: xamarin, uwp

We are getting following exception when we try to call `storagefolder.getfilesasync()` method in Xamarin Forms UWP enviornment.

is ther any alternative to that?

Comment: Can you put more details about this error?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the reason is that you are trying to use files inside the shared Portable Class Library. Because this library is shared across UWP, Android and iOS, you can't use Windows specific `StorageFile` there.

To work around this, you will need to create an **interface** for file access and **implement it for each operating system** separately. Working with files is very well described [in Xamarin Documentation](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/working-with/files/#Saving_and_Loading_Files).

Comment: Hi Martin, Thanks for you reply. The thing is this, the issue occourring not in PCL but in Xamarin-Forms Shared project. and I am writing the code in Platform dependent block. Another thing is objStorageFolder.GetFileAsync("FileName.txt") does work fine, but objStorageFolder.GetFilesAsync() is not working.

Comment: In support to my previous comments, if you like then I can send the sample code as well.

Comment: Yes, that will help a lot :-)